# Type provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any): any'

Tags: typescript

I have a generic class and I want to restrict which types can be used. Specifically, I want them to be classes and to have a method called hasPrimitives. Moreover, I want to pass the constructor of that class as a parameter of a function of the generic class to be able to build new instances. Here's an example of what I've thought in order to accomplish it:

```
type HasPrimitives = {
    new(...args: any): any,
    hasPrimitives(): boolean
}

class FirstClass {
    id: number;

    constructor(id: number){
        this.id = id;
    }

    hasPrimitives() {
        return true;
    }
}

class GenericClass<T extends HasPrimitives> {
    testFunction(example: T) {
        console.log(example.hasPrimitives())
    }

    build(Ctor: new (...args: ConstructorParameters<T>) => T) {
        // get the arguments somehow
        return new Ctor(args);
    }
}

const genericInstance = new GenericClass<FirstClass>();
```

I could use `any` as type of args, but I think it's a better idea to use ConstructorParameters so I could restrict it more. However, I'm getting an error: `Type 'FirstClass' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any): any'`. How could I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Please fix syntax error, `args` in `return new Ctor(args);` is not defined at all, how do you want to use it ?

Comment: It's an example. Basically I want to get primitives from a database and then construct my domain entity by using Ctor.

Comment: still, how do you want to pass args? as an argument to `build` method ?

Comment: "It's an example" but unfortunately not a [mre] so anything we tell you will be just a guess.  You can't call `new Ctor(args)` without `args`; where should `args` come from?  Maybe they are args to the `build` method like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nr9q3w)?  Or maybe something completely different?  Help us to help you.